# The Lie within The Truth

Tags: pattern, enigmatic-puzzle

And, lo! did the heavens open up to mine eyes and I did seeth the truth of the universe. The circular constant did pour forth from the mouth of angels and bury within my mind and I saw that it was good. The LORD spoketh thus, saying "THIS IS THE TRUTH POURED OUT FOR YOU AND FOR MANY. SPREAD MY WORD AMONGST MY PEOPLE." And I did see that the word was wrong. I found the truth within the lie and knew it to be so. Find the truth for thyself! Detect the lie within the truth as it was said unto me.

> 3.14159266358989323846264338327950388419816939937510582097494559231781640628621890962803482534212706798214808651328240664709384461955068223172535950812848111745028410370193852110555964472294895493038196442981098566503344612847574923379778316527120100914564856692346035861045432664821339360726024914127372458700660631558817488152092096282925409171536436789259036001133053054882046652138414695194151160943305727036575959195309218611738193261179310511854807446237996274956735188575272489122793818301194912983367336244065664308602139494639522473719070217986094370277053921717629317675238467481846766940513200056812714526356082778577134275778960917363717872146844090122495343014654958537105079227968925892354201995611212902196086403441815981362977477130996051870721134999999
>   ...

Comment: $\pi$ - this is -0.000000010000100000000000000000001000001

Comment: Is this posting meant to give support to wacko conspiracy theories that the Twin Towers in lower Manhattan weren't brought down on 2011/09/11 by two jet planes crashing into them and setting off massive fires? If so, please show some good taste and delete this posting. If not, please clarify what you intend to achieve with the subliminal message.

Comment: @Mico I hide the phrase in a lot of puzzles. If anything, I'm poking fun at the conspiracy theorists because this particular mantra is so easily proved meaningless.

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't realized that you use this phrase repeatedly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Find all the indices where the number doesn't match the corresponding digit of pi:

> (-1),9,14,34,40,61,66,78,81,82,96,116,129,134,146,166,185,205,210,215,227,229,234,235,248,267

Then take the differences and convert to letters:

> jetfuelcantmeltsteelbeams

Comment: I had got the indices, but that was impressively fast.  True about the melting, but it does substantially weaken [popular mechanics](http://www.popularmechanics.com/military/a6384/debunking-911-myths-world-trade-center/)

Comment: @DrXorile That's just one of the boilerplate texts I hide in my puzzles because I'm more interested in the "how it's hidden" instead of the "what is hidden". I give it no great weight in this context as it's just a puzzle.

Comment: It's cute.  I was entertained!

Comment: Where is the `(-1)` from?

Comment: @rwilson04 The (-1) is just added to make the first difference work. It reflects the fact that all the characters at indices 0, 1, ..., 8 do match, so the previous position would be -1.